# Different 'Open with' icon in Winforms Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a code editing Winforms application using C# and have added a default icon for my form.

I've noticed that several apps (such as Notepad++ and Atom) have two different icons: one for the main shortcut of the application, and the other one which is displayed when trying to open several files with the app.

For example, Atom's main icon looks like this:

[image]

and when changing the default app for opening a certain extension such as `.txt`, the icon for those files looks like this:

[image]

I already wrote the process command line arguments logic, when opening a file with my editor. My question would be: am I able to do a similar thing for my Winforms application? The first icon I already have, but I'm willing to also have a second icon for files that have my app as a default way to open them.

In my case, they look like this:

[image]
[image]

but I would want a different icon for the `test.txt` file.

Comment: The icon to use for an associated extension is defined in the Registry. It can be an Icon resource (`myprog.exe %3` - third icon), or a path to an `.ico` file

Comment: @Jimi Does this mean that just adding multiple icons as resources is enough for it do to the job?

Comment: @Jimi ... or do I actually need to do modifications in the Registry file?

Comment: Means that the icon used in a shortcut and the icon used when an extension is associated to a command, can be two different icons. Both a Shell link and the Registry provide means to specify which one to use in that context. See [AssocQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-assocquerystringw)

Comment: @Jimi Unfortunately I don't really understand how I should use this function to change the default icon for opening a certain file. I'm guessing these calls shouldn't be done directly in my app code (`.cs`), but in some sort of installer or as a separate program?

Comment: @Jimi as far as I see, `AssocQueryStringW` only verifies if a certain app is associated with a certain extension, but doesn't really help with what I need.

Comment: Of course an installer can do that (both generate a Shell Link and associate the executable to an extension). You can also do that by *manually* adding / changing the association in the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` when you need to (if a *secondary* icon is specified, you should periodically monitor your entry, to preserve the association details), after your app class is registered. Remember to call [SHChangeNotify()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shchangenotify) with `SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED` after -- Yes, `AssocQueryString` is used to just query the state